# How to hi-lighten with red border when multi check box fails validation.

Tags: 6, forms

I've been searching around for days but can't find the solution.. I know this is a core bug and have found two solutions on http://drupal.org but both of them don't work for multi check box validation on my site (It works for single check box and multi radio buttons though).

These are what I have found:

[Required radios/checkboxes are not validated (D6)](http://drupal.org/node/259292#comment-4817446)

[move checkboxes error class to parent div, so that checkboxes can be given a red border like other fields](http://drupal.org/node/44933#comment-2358422)

My problem is that it's not outputting the error classes only for multi check box even after using those methods above. 
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this module: [Checkbox Validate](http://drupal.org/project/checkbox_validate) ?

> Corrects bugs in Drupal core:
>
> - Checkboxes set as required not displaying required symbol (install this module to display)
> - Checkboxes set as required behave as optional (install this module to make behave
>     as required field)
>
> This is the related D6 issue: [#259292: Required radios/checkboxes are not validated (D6)](http://drupal.org/node/259292).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've actually already installed this module and validation is correctly working. Also the error message "--- is required"shows correctly on the top of the page.But only the thing is that it doesn't hi-lighten multi check box with red border even if the validation fails.